# I have created 1 image folder & inside it many image folders. How to display images from those folders in asp.net repeater?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater_userprofile" OnItemCommand="repeater_userprofile_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 0px">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtncustomerdetails" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("user_id") %>'>
                            <div class="member-item" style="height: 220px; width: 130px">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_user" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("photo","~/Categories/Doctor/{0}") %>'
                                            Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                                        <%--<asp:Image runat="server" Height="160" Width="160" ID="img1" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("photo","~/Categories/doctor/{0}") %>' />--%>
                                        <%--   <div class="item-overlay top"></div>--%>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("first_name") %>' ID="lblfirstname"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("last_name") %>' ID="lbllastname"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsubcategory" Text='<%#Eval("subcategory_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbllocation" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("user_id")%>'
                                        Text='<%#Eval("location_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnlike" OnClick="lbtnlike_click">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblprofile_like_count"></asp:Label>
                                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg" style="color: #d8aa46"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <img src="Images/ratings.png" height="20px" width="50px" style="color: #d8aa46" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please compose question properly. And it should be more like I am "trying" instead of "how".

Comment: All I see is a repeater template. What image folder? What images?